# Error in handling a series of async functions using dispatchGroup in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, alamofire, grand-central-dispatch

I have a project with 2 sets of async functions which should be executed in order. After all async functions are executed, I'm trying to run `function3`.

Here is a high level structure of my code:

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    let dispatchGroup2 = DispatchGroup()
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        asyncFunc1()

        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            asyncFunc2()
        }

        dispatchGroup2.notify(queue: .main) {
            print("all done")
            function3()
        }
    }

    func asyncFunc1() {
        for item in itemArray {
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            Alamofire.request(urlString).responseString { response in
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }
    }

    func asyncFunc2() {
        for item in itemArray2 {
            dispatchGroup2.enter()
            Alamofire.request(urlString).responseString { response in
                dispatchGroup2.leave()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My expectation is that functions run in order of `asyncFunc1() -> asyncFunc2() -> function3()`.
When I actually run this app, I see that `dispatchGroup2.notify` is triggered at the beginning when program runs and never gets called after `asyncFunc2` is done. What's wrong over here? I've tried doing with one `dispatchGroup` variable instead of having 2 (`dispatchGroup` and `dispatchGroup2`) but this didn't work again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a simple refactoring to *encapsulate* those [`DispatchGroup`s](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup) inside the corresponding asynchronous functions:

```
func asyncFunc(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    for ... {
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        request ... {
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
    }
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) { 
        completion() // Async function completed! 
    }
}
```

This would result in a very nice/compact top-level solution:

```
asyncFunc1 {
    self.asyncFunc2 {
        print("all done")
        self.function3()
    }
}
```

---

**Initial bug**. Your original issue was caused by calling `notify(queue:)` *before* the corresponding `enter()` method. Your dispatch group was over even before it began ;)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much for pointing out my bug and suggesting a new answer. I wish I can upvote this multiple times ;)